# callback method in the interface is being invoked in the MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass  some data from the `onPostExecute()` to the `MainActivity`. So when `doInBackground()` is finished the `onPostExecute()` is being invoked and the condition  `route!=0` is being entered (Since I have debugged it) but I am getting anything in the MainActivity.

The method `onAsyncTaskFinishedForTesting` is not being invoked in the MaiActivity so when I set Breakpoint at the start of it `boolean test = true;`. I am overriding all methods in the interface in the MainActivity.

How can I fix it?

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
  .....
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    PostData sender = new PostData(TrackingService.this);
                sender.post_data(jSONString, this);

    }


}
```

** PostData class:**

```
 public class PostData {
        private AsyncTaskCallback callback;
        String jSONString;

            public PostData(AsyncTaskCallback callback) {
             this.callback = callback;
            }

            public void post_data(String jSONString, Context context) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);


    }
        ....
      class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> {

         .....
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer>  result) {    
                if (route != 0) {
                    System.out.println("test f PostData: "+ direction +": "+ route);                
                    callback.onAsyncTaskFinishedForTesting(direction, route);

                } else {
                    Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the route are null!!!");
                }
            }

      }
    }
```

**AsyncTaskCallback Interface**

```
public interface AsyncTaskCallback {
    void onAsyncTaskFinished(String direction, int route);
    void onAsyncTaskFinished(ArrayList<Integer> result);
    void onAsyncTaskFinishedForTesting(String direction, int route);
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
     ......
    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskFinishedForTesting(String direction, int route) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean test = true;
        if (test) {
            test = false;
            System.out.println("test f MainActivity: "+ direction +": "+ route);

            tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDirect);
            tvD.setText(direction);
            tvR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRoute);
            tvR.setText(route);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please also provide the PostData constructor and the part where you create the PostData instance

Comment: I could not see where you register the callback. You should be seeing a null pointer exception.

Comment: @AndreiTudorDiaconu: I have added it. Please take a look.

Comment: @Fildor: I am not getting any error.

Comment: I also asked for the PostData instance creation. I imagine you do this in the activity?

Comment: @AndreiTudorDiaconu: The instance is in another class names `Trackingservice.` here is the line `PostData sender = new PostData(TrackingService.this);`

Comment: I am creating the instance in another class `TrackingService` but I just to pass the route and direction to the MainActivity for testing purposes when I get response from the server. I it possible to manage it with callback method?

Comment: Well, you give the PostData constructor a TrackingService instance. That is what `onPostExecute` will be using when it does `callback.onAsyncTaskFinishedForTesting(direction, route);` . So, if you want it to do things in the MainActivity, you need to give it the MainActivity instance.

Comment: @AndreiTudorDiaconu:  but I cant start what I aim from the MainActivity so I cant pass an instance to  the PostData constructur  from the MainActivity also I cant pass an instance to it from the MainActivity. Is this case better to manage with intent?

Comment: I only showed you what is wrong and explained what you need to do regarding your callback. You can use a BroadcastReceiver as a solution, for instance, but since you now understand why your callback is not called, I wish you good luck with your research from here on. Maybe post a new question regarding communication between Service and Activity. Please do research first.

Comment: You won't get anything in the MainActivity unless you instantiate Post Data in it. As Andrei said, use a broadcast receiver for your service to activity communication